# Hiding list item seperator for few list items

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I have many navigation drawers (mostly in Google Apps) where few of the items are having no List item seperators, while some list items are having list seperators.
I want to achieve the same functionality for my app.

can anybody please help me understand the implementation?
How can i hide list seperator for few of the list items while others have it?

regards,

Rajan

Comment: Use a listview with different layouts for each row. Making some rows separators: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4777272/android-listview-with-different-layout-for-each-row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each list item row use this layout:

```
<LinearLayout>
    (...)
    <View
    android:id="@+id/viewSeparator1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="#646464"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Then on your adapter use this

```
public class DrawerListAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    (...)

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        (...)
        View mViewSeparator = convertView.findViewByID(R.id.viewSeparator1);

        //I dont know when you want to show a separator so replace this line with the apropriate check: for example: if(position == 0) etc
        if(hasSeparator)
            mViewSeparator.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        else
            mViewSeparator.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Comment: Dont forget to remove the default separator from the listview since you are providing a separator for each row:

use: android:divider="@null" or yourListView.setDivider(null);

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But i could not get how to evaluate it for each list item. Currently I am applying adapter like this 'code'  adapter = new DrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), navDrawerItems);
  mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);'code' . How can i apply the above code in my case.

Comment: Edited answer: The code i gave you needs to be inside getView from your custom adapter class